# MySql syntax error during user creation when there is no apparent error

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, moodle

I'm trying to install Moodle using Ubuntu using the following guide: [Step-by-step Installation Guide for Ubuntu](https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Step-by-step_Installation_Guide_for_Ubuntu)

I'm currently on step 6 where I have to create a mySQL user with the correct permissions and this is where I'm getting stuck.

The 1st command - `create user 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';` works fine

However the 2nd command -

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,DROP,INDEX,ALTER ON moodle.* TO user1@localhost
IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';
```

Returns the error message - `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'password1'' at line 1`

The installation manual mentions that this may be a problem so advises me to use - `SELECT password('password1');` in order to get a hash value to overcome the problem.

However instead of giving me a hash value it comes up with the same error of - `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('password1')' at line 1`

I am a beginner to all this so I'd appreciate any responses, thanks in advance!

Comment: You already set the password in `CREATE USER`. Just leave the `IDENTIFIED BY` clause off of the `GRANT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need apostrophes around the name and the host in your command, like:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,DROP,INDEX,ALTER ON moodle.* TO 'user1'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';
```

EDIT

According to the comments, slightly changing the command fixed the syntax error:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,DROP,INDEX,ALTER ON moodle.* TO 'user1'@'localhost';
```

Comment: I tried that and it still comes up with the same error sadly

Comment: @Mustafa this may depend on versions of MySQL, try without the identified by clause, as in ```GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,DROP,INDEX,ALTER ON moodle.* TO 'user1'@'localhost';```

Answer (score -1):

*First* Create user ‘moodleuser’@’localhost’ identified by ‘yourpassword’;

*Then* grant select,insert,update,delete,create,create temporary tables,drop,index,alter on moodle.* to 'moodleuser'@'localhost';

Comment: i was using mysql 8.0 apparently grant doesnt work with create user in 8.0

Comment: don't copy and paste answers, please

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).